# Graph functions & color area under curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Could anyone help me with the attached images below as far as coding the axis's and shading the area? I'm new to anything graphing in LaTeX and would love to have some guidance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: [Pgfplots: how to fill bounded area under a curve using addplot and fill?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164991/pgfplots-how-to-fill-bounded-area-under-a-curve-using-addplot-and-fill?rq=1)

Comment: Start from http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162808/3235 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79508/